# How to initialise BigInteger after creating instantces (constructor can't be called)

Tags: java, biginteger

Imagine an instance of `BigInteger`, then how to initialize it after creating instance?

For example:

```
BigInteger t = new BigInteger();
```

How to put a value in `t`?

If the constructor cannot be called, then what can be done, to put the value in the object?

Comment: To learn how to use a class, read its documentation. All the standard classes are documented: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. The documentation of BigInteger is here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what specifically is confusing you as you'd initialize the items in the BigInteger array as you would any other object array. e.g.,

```
  BigInteger t2 [] = new BigInteger[2];

  t2[0] = new BigInteger("2");
  t2[1] = BigInteger.ZERO; // ZERO, ONE, and TEN are defined by constants

  // or

  BigInteger[] t3 = {new BigInteger("2"), BigInteger.ZERO};
```

**Edit 1:**
Ah, now I understand your problem: you want to create a BigInteger instance and then later set its value.  The answer is the same as for Strings: **you can't**, and that it is because BigIntegers like Strings are **immutable** and can't be changed once created. For this reason the class has no "setter" methods. The way to change the value of a BigInteger *variable* is to set it to a new BigInteger instance.

Comment: ok, thanks, just if it would not have been array, and object would have been created, then how did value had been put in BigInteger

Comment: @CoolEulerProject: Please see the modification (**Edit 1**) in my answer above.

Comment: Full Of Eels ,thanks,"BigIntegers like Strings are immutable and can't be changed once created"

Answer (score 5):

To convert a long (or a regular integer) to BigInteger, use the static factory method valueOf.  The call `BigInteger.valueOf(<i>someInteger</i>)` returns a new `BigInteger` object holding the integer value you specify.  You could also use new `BigInteger("" + <i>someInteger</i>)` to get the same thing, but this is clunkier.

Comment: thanks, but how to replace the value in BigInteger using string

Comment: BigInteger has a constructor that accepts a string representation of a number and which creates a BigInteger object for you.

Comment: Read the documentation. Its first sentence is: *Immutable arbitrary-precision integers*. A BigInteger is immutable. Once created, it can't be changed anymore. Construct another one.

Comment: BigInteger has a constructor that accepts a string representation of a number and which creates a BigInteger object for you.  Example  BigInteger b = new BigInteger("3790171387138978419174");

Comment: @ ncmathsadist thanks, but my question was can it(BigInteger) be modified(replace with another string), Answer is No(See answer of JB Nizet)

Answer (score 3):

here are some examples:

```
BigInteger t = BigInteger.valueOf(23);
int i = 66;
t = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
t = BigInteger.ZERO
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
//initialize with zero
BigInteger t = BigInteger.ZERO;

//if i is any value that is to be assigned 
t=t.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```